# iPhone - why the fullscreen does not work but it works with iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

[image]
In iPad Pro, Air, Mini the same settings are working, but when i use iPhone 7 real device and start the same app, it does not go as full screen like it does with any iPad.

Is there any other settings i might need/missing to make both platform run my app correctly?

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //[self myMethodHere:@"testing/pesting"];
  [self showASimpleExitButtonOnBottomCenter];
}
```

Comment: Maybe your splash screen is not correct.

Comment: I dont have any splash screen. it launch the Storyboard only storyboard i have.

Comment: Try to load splash . Then it will working fine.

Comment: NO - it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem was:

[image]

1) remove "Launch image source"

2) Add "Launch Screen file" > new LaunchScreen.storyboard

Answer (score 1):

Follow the image, I had the same issue once for this section. See it, if it helps you.

[image]

due Launch Images Source the problem was arised.

Hope it helps you..

Comment: I have posted the correct answer. please vote me up.